# SVG fallback for IE8 inline attempt

Tags: javascript, svg, internet-explorer-8

```
<img src="images/logo.svg" onerror="this.src=images/logo.png;this.onerror=null;" id="logo">
```

This is not working for me in IE8, what am I doing wrong?

Comment: if the svg exists, ie8 doesnt seem to throw an error, even if it can not display it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You want `this.src='images/logo.png'` with quotes to make it a string.

Answer (score 1):

if the svg exists, ie8 doesnt seem to throw an error, even if it can not display it.

using jquery and modernizr, adding this to $(document).ready() seemed to work:

```
$('html.no-svg img.svg').each(function() {
    $(this).trigger('error').removeClass('svg');
});
```

Comment: This is the same problem I'm having.

Comment: I figured it out. I was using IE11 with the developer tools set to IE8 to test. Trying it out in actual IE8 seems to work.